# Switch to windows desktop from uwp app using button click in UWP App

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, winui

I am trying to switch users from Windows application screen to Windows desktop using a single button click(C#) in the UWP application. please help, I am not able to find any solution. Thanks

Comment: When you say `switch users from Windows application screen to Windows desktop`,  what kind of behavior do you want to get? The app lost focus? Or the app becomes minimized?

Comment: I need the exact same behavior as when we click at the most right bottom area of the start menu bar of window 10.

Comment: Do you mean click the taskbar? Or click the systray icons?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a "Restricted Capability" to your app's manifest file. This capability is "runFullTrust" and it lets your UWP app launch any Win32 App in the system using this class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041

Please note that adding this restricted capability will most likely prevent you from submitting the app to the store as it will fail verification.

Microsoft, however, allows some apps with those capabilities to pass the review process but only in some limited cases. Please consult this page for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities

Comment: Thank for reply, I don't want to run a win32 app app. What I want, that my app move user to windows desktop screen on a button click.